# convert sql server 2008 database to sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Hi I have done this before but cannot find out how i did it. I have a website that has a sql server 2008 db which needs to be put on a sql server 2005. i remember scripting it down to recreated it in 2005 i thought i did it through the 'generate script' wizard but this didnt script down the data, just the tables and stored procedures. what would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are actually doing it right, you just have to select the proper options.

- Right click on DB.
- Select Tasks
- Select Generate Scripts
- Choose your objects
- Under scripting options, click on Advanced

Under `Script for Server Version`, choose `SQL Server 2005`

Under `Types of data to script`, choose `Schema and Data`

Comment: well i cant see any options to include data or anything?

Comment: it works but i get a system.outofmemoryexception when i try running it. :( so need to find another method i guess.

Answer (score 0):

use the following convert options while doing the data export:

- Script for Server Version = `'SQL Server 2005'`
- Script Data' = `'True'`
- Script Database Create' = `'True'`

edit: check out http://www.sqlservermart.com/HowTo/MSSQL_Convert_2008_To_2005.aspx for more info :-)

Comment: so are you saying you sql export instead of generate script?

Answer (score 0):

Try DBSourceTools.
http://dbsourcetools.codeplex.com.
It is specifically designed to script databases to disk, including all objects and data, and then re-create them through a deployment target.
I have done this many times before from 2008 to 2005, and the tool takes care of all database dependencies and data.

Comment: cool, the issue i had was once i had the database scripted down it was to big to execute in ss2005. i kept getting a 'not enough memory' error.